# ext4fs: Adding multiple flash storage (SSD) into one LVM volume (one at a time) + resizefs: Is it friendly for the flash storage

Tags: filesystems, ssd

In the said use case as the title: The scenario to be, for example:
In the beginning, I had one SSD drive with ext4fs, then after the storage was not sufficient, I added another drive by LVM + resizefs, and again add the 3rd drive..., and so on.

I assume that the logical block address in ext4fs should be set increasingly from the 1st SSD, and then 2nd SSD, 3rd SSD, ...

The question is: Will my data be stored firstly on the 1st drive, and then the 2nd drive, ...

If that's the case, it's really not friendly to flash storage:  We know that if a physical storage is used about 90% and more, the efficiency will drop (due to flash moving page/erase page effects).  It's bad for both access latency performance and the disk life time.